# vba vlookup 424 object required error in For loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I've new to VBA and have been working on and off with it for almost a year. What I'm trying to execute is based on a selection from a drop down somewhere in the worksheet it changes the data in column B from names to logins based off a vlookup. I keep getting the 'object required' error so I'm guessing that means I haven't declared whatever the result of the vlookup is as something.

It works fine with `s = 3` so I'm assuming it has something to do with the For loop not liking the data I'm trying to pass through it.

```
sub show_by_login()

'first row that is evaluated is in row 5

Dim s As Long
s = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H17").Value
If s = 1 Then
Exit Sub
ElseIf s = 2 Then

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Double
    For i = 2 To LastRow

    Dim str As Double
    str = Sheets("Sheets2").Cells(i + 3, 1).Value
    Cells(i + 3, 2) = Application.VLookup(str, Sheets("Roster").Range("A:C"), 2, False).Value
    Next i

ElseIf s = 3 Then
i = 5

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i), Sheets("Roster").Range("A:C"), 2, False)

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you receive the error?

Comment: On the ElseIf line for s= 2. specifically for the VLookup function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cells(i + 3, 2) = Application.VLookup(str, Sheets("Roster").Range("A:C"), 2, False).Value
```

vlookup returns a cell value, not a Range object, so drop the .Value from the end of that line

```
Cells(i + 3, 2) = Application.VLookup(str, Sheets("Roster").Range("A:C"), 2, False)
```

Comment: I wondered if that’s what it was. I wrote it originally without “.value” but then it was throwing 1004 errors. I found a couple of other resources here that help deal with that so I’ll filter through those as well for assistance.

Comment: So it seemed to work although I swear I had it set up this way before so I was dubious. Thanks! `ElseIf s = 2 Then
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    LastRow = Sheets("Bourg Bind").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Double
    
        For i = 2 To LastRow
        
        Cells(i + 3, 2) = Application.VLookup(Sheets("Bourg Bind").Cells(i + 3, 1), Sheets("Roster").Range("A:C"), 2, False)
          
        Next i`